# Angular directive where one of two attributes are required

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-directive

How do I write a directive that requires either `ng-model` or `k-ng-model`? The documentation doesn't cover this :(

```
app.directive('myDir', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel || kNgModel',
        // omitted
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass them in as an array of strings.

You can't tell Angular at least one of these needs to be available, so set them as optional and check in the link function if one of both is available. Update your code to:

```
app.directive('myDir', function () {
    return {
        require: ['?ngModel', '?kNgModel'],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers){
            if(!controllers[0] && !controllers[1]){
                throw 'myDir expects either ng-model or k-ng-model to be defined';
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Hmm I'm getting a null on controllers[1] when k-ng-model is set. That is normalized to kNgModel right?

Comment: It is normalized as you say, is `k-ng-model` defined on the same element `myDir` is defined on?

Comment: Ye it's used like so: <div my-dir="" k-ng-model="foo"> but I have a hunch it's a kendo issue

Comment: That's very well possible, I've actually never encountered a case where the controller would end up as `null`. In case an optional required directive is not available, this would result in an `undefined`, the length of the array is always equal to the length of the `require` array, could you put your code in a Fiddle maybe?

Comment: It appears that k-ng-model isn't a directive - so that explains it

Comment: IC, it's merely an attribute? Still bit puzzled about the fact it does not result in an error